# How to resolve oAuth 2.0 Google Spreadsheets authentication issue?

Tags: php, authentication, oauth, google-sheets, token

I'm building a server-side application that would need to authenticate with Google Spreadsheets API and read data from it. Using this [PHP client](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client) with [Google APIs client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client).

What I need to do is to authenticate with Google without user interaction.

Installed everything with [composer](https://getcomposer.org/) and loaded with autoloader.php.

The problem I'm having is, in [this section](https://github.com/asimlqt/php-google-spreadsheet-client#bootstrapping) of the documentation, an `$accessToken` variable is used which I can't generate. I created a project in Google Developers Console and oAuth 2.0 credentials with service account client ID. As a result, I got two files - `JSON and p12`, alongside with the `CLIENT ID`, `EMAIL ADDRESS` and `PUBLIC KEY FINGERPRINTS` credentials, which I don't know how to use to obtain the authorization token.

Also, I'm facing a `redirect_uri_mismatch` error and I can't set it up in Google Developers Console.

The `authenticate` method in `OAuth2.php` is requiring a `$code` variable which I don't have and don't know how to obtain.

If I could obtain that `$accessToken` variable, I could try to debug further.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName(GOOGLE_APPLICATION_NAME);
$client->setClientId(GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);

$key = file_get_contents(GOOGLE_KEY_FILE);
$cred = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(
    GOOGLE_CLIENT_EMAIL,
    array(GOOGLE_SPREADSHEETS_URL),
    $key
);

$client->setAssertionCredentials($cred);

if($client->getAuth()->isAccessTokenExpired()) {
    $client->getAuth()->refreshTokenWithAssertion($cred);
}

$service_token = json_decode($client->getAccessToken());
$accessToken = $service_token->access_token;

use Google\Spreadsheet\DefaultServiceRequest;
use Google\Spreadsheet\ServiceRequestFactory;

$serviceRequest = new DefaultServiceRequest($accessToken);
ServiceRequestFactory::setInstance($serviceRequest);

$spreadsheetService = new Google\Spreadsheet\SpreadsheetService();
$spreadsheetFeed = $spreadsheetService->getSpreadsheets();
```

GOOGLE_SPREADSHEETS_URL is https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds and GOOGLE_KEY_FILE is the location of your XXX.p12 file.

I do hope this will help somebody in a similar situation.